# Class in class in class in python, how to share information

Tags: python, database, peewee

I am trying to create a class for a database using peewee in python. This results in nested classes due to peewee's use of a class named meta in the models. My question is, how do I define the database (=db) within the class Meta? Is there perhaps a better way?

```
import peewee as pe

    class DataBase():
        class SensorType(pe.Model):
            name = pe.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

            class Meta:
                database = db

    def ___init___(self,filename='sensors.db'):
        db = pe.SqliteDatabase(filename)
        db.connect()
        db.create_tables([self.SensorType],safe=True)

    def add_sensor(self,typeName):
        type, created = self.SensorType.get_or_create(name=typeName)
        return type, created

    def get_sensors(self):
        return self.SensorType.select().order_by(self.SensorType.name)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    myDb = DataBase()
    myDb.add_sensor('Test')

    for type in myDb.get_sensors():     
        print(type.name)
```

I found that defining the classes within the `__init__` function of my main class works. But it is probably not the preferred approach.

```
import peewee as pe

class DataBase():
    def __init__(self,filename='sensors.db'):        
       db = pe.SqliteDatabase(filename)
       db.connect()

        class SensorType(pe.Model):
           typename = pe.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
           class Meta:
              database = db             

       self.SensorType = SensorType          
       db.create_tables([self.SensorType],safe=True)


    def add_sensor_type(self,typeName):
       type, created = self.SensorType.get_or_create(typename=typeName)
       return type, created

    def get_sensor_types(self):
       return self.SensorType.select()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    myDb = DataBase()
    myDb.add_sensor_type('Test')

    for type in myDb.get_sensor_types():     
        print(type.id, type.typename)
```

Comment: A better way? Yes, don't use nested classes.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't seem to be a good approach. Do you have any hints on how to avoid it in my example?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of nesting classes, try inheritance.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/6469907) has some fairly decent information on how to use inheritance and metaclasses in Python.

Looking at the quickstart example for [peewee](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/quickstart.html), does something like this work for you?

```
import peewee

class BaseModel(peewee.Model):            
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(BaseModel, self).__init__()
        Meta.database = db

    class Meta:
        database = None

class SensorType(BaseModel):
    def __init__(self, db):
        super(SensorType, self).__init__(db)

    name = peewee.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class DataBase():
    def __init__(self, filename='sensors.db'):
        self.db = peewee.SqliteDatabase(filename)
        self.sensor_type = SensorType(self.db)
        self.db.connect()
        self.db.create_tables([self.sensor_type], safe=True)

    def add_sensor(self, typeName):
        type, created = self.sensor_type.get_or_create(name=typeName)
        return type, created

    def get_sensors(self):
        return self.sensor_type.select().order_by(self.sensor_type.name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DataBase()

    db.add_sensor('Test')
    [print(type.name) for type in db.get_sensors()]
```

Mess around with the model's `__init__` method to see if you can pass a database instance upon initialization.

I would stay *far* away from defining a class inside a method.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you help, and the link to the post on inheritance. Good reading.

Comment: I get the following error when i run this code: `NameError: name 'Meta' is not defined` - it is not supposed to be a working example?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [this approach](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#run-time-database-configuration) from peewee documentation. It works and I avoid the nested classes:

```
import peewee as pe
database = pe.SqliteDatabase(None)

class BaseModel(pe.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class SensorType(BaseModel):
    name = pe.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class DataBase():
    def __init__(self, filename='sensors.db'):
        database.init(filename)
        self.sensor_type = SensorType()
        database.connect()
        database.create_tables([self.sensor_type], safe=True)        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db = DataBase('test.db')
```

Comment: I was not sure how you felt about a global variable.  Glad you found a solution that works for you!